# How to create a rectangle in HTML and put some text on it?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, css-shapes

I want to create a rectangle in html and put some text on it.
And when on clicking  on that rectangle it should redirect to another page..
Any pointers?

Comment: Hi any code you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an a tag with a display setting:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px; /*sets height of element*/
  background: cornflowerblue; /*sets the background of this element (here a solid colour)*/
  transition: all 0.6s; /*sets a transition (for hover effect)*/
  padding-left: 20px; /*sets 'padding'*/
  padding-right: 20px; /*sets 'padding'*/
  line-height: 50px; /*for this, it sets vertical alignment*/
}
a:hover {
  background: tomato; /*sets background colour*/
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Some Text</a>
```

Within your `href` attribute, you should place the link to your next page:

```
<a href="/Home/NextPageDirectory">Link Text</a>
```